# Ionic change Datetime height and Color

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I have problems with changing the height and color of my
`<ion-datetime>`. 
I'm pretty new in Web development and SCSS.

I tried overriding the ionic sass variables but it didn't work (maybe it is because they are for ios, android and windows phone?). 
It is mainly a Web application running on a RaspberryPi with a 320x240 resolution.

In the picture you can see, it just needs to be a little bit smaller for fitting the screen. 
And it would be nice to change its background color. 
Thanks for your help :)

Screenshot (date-time resolution):

[image]

Comment: did you find answer?

Answer (score 0):

try

```css
.picker-md .picker-prefix,
.picker-md .picker-suffix,
.picker-md .picker-opt.picker-opt-selected {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Montserrat-Medium;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(227, 123, 38, 0.342);
    box-shadow:  0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
      0 -0px 1px rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.4),
      0 1.5px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.picker-md .picker-opt {
    color: map-get($colors,bg);
    font-family: Montserrat-Light;
}
.picker-md .picker-button,
.picker-md .picker-button.activated {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
}
```